# MongoDB/Express Query Object from URL

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Sorry in advance for what I'm sure is going to be really straightforward. My brain is just not seeing it.

I have a database. I'd like to query that database from the frontend, using the arguments in my URI. We're not at that part yet. Express/Node on the back.

When I use this query:

```
dbo.collection("archive").find({OBJECT: 'RRP68'},{ projection: {
```

I get some results, as expected, of entries featuring that object. When I try this:

```
    var query = {OBJECT: 'RRP68'};
    dbo.collection("archive").find({query},{ projection: {
```

I get no results. Initially I thought the problem was how I consumed the URI element, then I thought scoping (even though pagination works fine in the same manner), but this is the most simplified version I could come up with that still didn't work. So clearly there's some syntax or structure concept or something along those lines I don't know, and can't seem to find in the docs.

Pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because this is what is happening right now

```
 dbo.collection("archive").find({{OBJECT: 'RRP68'}},{ projection: {
```

Do you see it? It's because of double curly brackets

This Will fix it

```
var query = {OBJECT: 'RRP68'};
dbo.collection("archive").find(query,{ projection: {
```

Comment: The real villain here was dyslexia all along. Thanks for catching it.